# Online documentation for IabHelper class from the Android billing samples?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-billing

The Android's developer guide for In-app billing V3 comes with a sample app called [TrivialDrive](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample). In it, there's an utility class called IabHelper, which the guide advise us to import on our own apps.

I would like to know if there is an online documentation for the IabHelper class? I searched through d.android.com but didn't find anything. Or should I just extract the Javadocs from the source files instead?

Answer (score 7):

Well, if anyone cares, I uploaded the JavaDoc to github: http://vibrunazo.github.com/IAPTest01/

So you can use it as an online reference when and IDE is not available.

Answer (score 2):

I used this as a documentation for the IabHelper :
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

...
but your documentation is nice !!